# Jython returns False to gettattr([alist],'__reversed__') while Python returns True

Tags: jython

While debuging why cmd2 wont load in in Jython, I found out that it breaks because Jython returns False to `gettattr([alist],'__reversed__')` while Python returns True.

I would assume that the correct result is True as a list *is* reversible..

Anyone knows what is going on?

my next option is to browse around Jython source.. and I am not looking forward to it ;)

BTW, I am using jython 2.5.1 on top of java "1.6.0_18" on ubuntu

Thx in advance for any hints

Comment: Please edit the question to reflect that you're looking for the \_\_reversed__ attribute and not the reversed attribute (You can escape the underscores or use indented code regions to prevent the underscores from being treated as markdown).

Answer (score 2):

It appears as if the __reversed__ attribute of lists in Jython is not implemented. I don't get the results you describe, if I call

```
getattr([], '__reversed__')
```

in Python 2.5.2, I get

```
>>> [].__reversed__
<built-in method __reversed__ of list object at 0x7f72581d7050>
```

And in Jython 2.5.1, I get

```
>>> [].__reversed__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__reversed__'
```

If it's returning `True` or `False` respectively, then you're probably not using a standard Python list.

In any case, it appears as if Jython doesn't support the __reversed__ attribute of lists to indicate that it is reversible. According to [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__reversed__), this feature appears to have been added to the CPython implementation in Python 2.6, which might explain why it doesn't appear in Jython 2.5.1. I do find that __reversed__ appears in Python 2.5.2, so it may have been back-ported to CPython, but just not officially supported.

For now, you can suggest that cmd2 be patched with something like the following:

```
def can_be_reversed(o):
    "return True if an object can be reversed by reverse()"
    return hasattr(o, '__reversed__') or \
        hasattr(o, '__len__') and hasattr(o, '__getitem__')
```